# How do I include a shortcut for my app in the VS2008 toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2008

i need open the project exe file from inside the visual studio 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Tools | Externals Tools... click "Add" then you point 'command' to the path of the .exe you would like to have run from the toolbar.

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer 
but i need it automatically added when me setup my developed application